# How is the link between local and global dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I am modifying a dataframe within a function but I do not want it to change the global variable.

I use two different ways to change my dataframe and they affect my global variable differently. The first method to add a new column by assigning a non-existent column modifies the global dataframe. By concatenation of a new column the global dataframe remains unchanged.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
            columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
def mutation(data):
     data['d'] = [1, 2, 3]
mutation(df)
print(df)
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
            columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
def mutation(data):
    data = pd.concat([data,pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns=['d'])], axis =1)
mutation(df)
print(df)
```

I expect that when I print df after calling the function I see columns a, b and c. But, the first method also shows column d.

Comment: I would recommend that you read this: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference It is because you are parsing-by-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the `data` object to the function, you are actually passing its reference to the function. So when you do in-place mutations on the object it points to, you can see these mutations outside of the function as well.

If you want to keep your original data un-mutated, pass a clone of the original data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
            columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
def mutation(data):
     data['d'] = [1, 2, 3]
mutation(df.copy())
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

The function operated on the clone, so the original data frame is unmodified.

The second example you've done is not an in-place operation on the original data frame: It instead creates a new data frame. So in the second example, your original DF is not modified.